# How do I contour a smoothScatter plot with missing values in r studio?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, contour

This is the code I am using

```
smoothScatter(longesttimeon$nhmc,longesttimeon$pt2,nrpoints=0)
smoothScatter(longesttimeon$nhmc,longesttimeon$pt2,nrpoints=0,colramp=colorRampPalette(c("white","dodgerblue2","gold","firebrick")))

library(readxl)
kern <- kde2d(longesttimeon$nhmc, longesttimeon$pt2)

contour(kern, drawlabels = FALSE, nlevels = 6,
        col = rev(heat.colors(6)), add = TRUE, lwd = 3)
```

I get this error sign

```
Error in kde2d(longesttimeon$nhmc, longesttimeon$pt2) : 
  missing or infinite values in the data are not allowed
```

I am trying to make it look like this

[image]

Comment: As per the error message, you need to remove cases with missing values.

Comment: I removed the missing values and it still tells me the same thing. I tried na.rm = TRUE but it takes the smoothScatterplot away and only shows the contour lines.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the data using `dput()`? It's difficult to troubleshoot further without reproducing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use dput() , I'm new to using R studio .

Comment: Run `dput(longesttimeon)` and copy/paste the output. If it's very long, maybe cut down on to, say 100 rows by running `dput(longesttimeon[1:100,])`

Comment: copy and paste the output here ? My data set contains close to 10,000 data points

Comment: As I mentioned, try `dput(longesttimeon[1:100,])`